# Multi-List to an order dictionary by different column

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a OrderedDict below, which column1 and column2 present a relationship

This created for me the following OrderedList

```
OrderedDict([('AD',
              [['A', 'Q_30', 100],
               ['A', 'Q_24', 74],
               ['B', 'Q_28', 37],
               ['B', 'Q_30', 100],
               ['C', 'Q_25', 38],
               ['C', 'Q_30', 100],
               ['D', 'D_4', 44],
               ['E', 'D_4', 44],
               ['F', 'D_5', 44]])
```

I would like to iterate over the elements, each time look at other row and collect column2.

eg.

1. element A contain Q_30 and Q24 and collect related member from other rows
2. element B contain Q_30, so collect Q24,Q28,Q30 and order by column3

```
OrderedDict([('AD',
              [{'Q_30':100, 'Q_24':74, 'Q_25':38, 'Q_28': 37}, {'D_4':44}, {'D_5':44}])
```

Answer (score 1):

When I understand this correctly, your "OrderedDict" is currently a tuple with a list inside, in which is another list and is meant to look like this:

```
OrderedList = ('AD',
               [['A', 'Q_30', 100],
                ['A', 'Q_24', 74],
                ['B', 'Q_28', 37],
                ['B', 'Q_30', 100],
                ['C', 'Q_25', 38],
                ['C', 'Q_30', 100],
                ['D', 'D_4', 44],
                ['E', 'D_4', 44],
                ['F', 'D_5', 44]])
```

and you want to convert it into a tuple with a list inside which holds dicts:

```
OrderedDict = ('AD',
               [{'Q_30': 100,
                 'Q_24': 74,
                 'Q_25': 38,
                 'Q_28': 37},
                {'D_4': 44},
                {'D_5': 44}])
```

In this case I am guessing you look for groupby():

```
from itertools import groupby

    OrderedList = ('AD',
               [['A', 'Q_30', 100],
                ['A', 'Q_24', 74],
                ['B', 'Q_28', 37],
                ['B', 'Q_30', 100],
                ['C', 'Q_25', 38],
                ['C', 'Q_30', 100],
                ['D', 'D_4', 44],
                ['E', 'D_4', 44],
                ['F', 'D_5', 44]])

for key, group in groupby(OrderedList[1], lambda x: x[0]):
    for thing in group:
        print("%s is a %s." % (thing[1], key))
```

Gives:

```
Q_30 is a A.
Q_24 is a A.
Q_28 is a B.
Q_30 is a B.
Q_25 is a C.
Q_30 is a C.
D_4 is a D.
D_4 is a E.
D_5 is a F.
```

This is not the full answer, but an example as I feel like it would be spoon-feeding otherwise